# Extracting the geometry of the parts not intersecting from 2 shapes overlapping each other in postgresql?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, overlapping-features, extract

This seems simple enough, yet i do not find a clear awnser on that peculiar matter. What i am trying to do is to extract the parts of a shape that doesn't intersect with another when the 2 of them are overlapping. In short, i am looking for something like ST_intersection but in reverse.

Comment: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html  ?

Comment: That was pretty much what i was looking for, thank you and sorry if the question was a bit silly but i had issues finding this in the doc for Postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ST_Difference**
Returns a geometry that represents that part of geometry A that does not intersect with geometry B.

[postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html)